# SQL Server 2008R2 - Cannot View DB Properties in SSMS or Query Database Files

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, blocking

I am trying to view the properties of a database but it fails in SSMS with below error in screenshot.
[image: SSMS database properties error]

I searched online for solutions but none have worked. These include change db owner to sa. The server files all look ok and all other databases on the server are ok. I also ran DBCC CHECKDB and that is clear of errors.

I try running the below SQL but it is blocked by **session id -2** with wait type **LCK_M_S**
There are no other connections open on this database.

Do I have any other options than a SQL Service restart?

```
SELECT
(SELECT SUM(CAST(df.size as float)) FROM sys.database_files AS df WHERE df.type in ( 0, 2, 4 ) ) AS [DbSize],
(SUM(a.total_pages) + (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CAST(df.size as bigint)), 0) FROM sys.database_files AS df WHERE df.type = 2 )) AS [SpaceUsed]
FROM
sys.partitions p join sys.allocation_units a on p.partition_id = a.container_id left join sys.internal_tables it on p.object_id = it.object_id
```

Comment: A blocking session_id of `-2` means that there is an orphaned Distributed Transaction. However, I don't have any advice to your actual question of how to resolve the issue without restarting (unless you happen to have a good understanding of your distributed transactions & can track down the issue based on just that).